# subprocess.call() not working Python

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, subprocess, system-calls

I am trying to pass arguments to an executable written in `C` from my script, however, the program is not executed and no console window appears which appears when the executable is run.

I have tried to run the executable using `os.system() and subprocess.call()`, both `return 0` which I think means the command executed successfully but my executable doesn't run.

What am I missing here?

```
subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Hello\myApp.exe", "-i abc.txt -o xyz.pdf"],shell=True)

os.system('"'+'C:\Program Files (x86)\Hello\myApp.exe -i abc.txt -o xyz.pdf'+'"');
```

I have tried running without arguments as well still the program doesn't execute.

Comment: Can you specify what "does not run" means? if this is equal to "opens a console window" then I can tell you it is not the same. You need additional arguments to tell the application to open a new console instead of using the one of python.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `myApp.exe` is a shell command such as `dir`; don't use `shell=True` on Windows.

If you use a list argument then each list item should be a separate argument for your program:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Hello\myApp.exe', #NOTE: `r''` literal
            '-i', 'abc.txt', '-o', 'xyz.pdf'])
```

Comment: I have tried this still not working. I have also tried to the run the executable by changing my current working directory in python and then calling the exe by `os.system(r'myApp.exe') subprocess.call([r'myApp.exe']); and by subprocess.check_call` still the executable doesn't run.

Comment: @user2498079: "not working" is not very informative. What happens if you run the code from my answer **as is**?

Comment: nothing. No console window pops nor the output file is generated.

Comment: @user2498079: ok. Do you run it from the command-line, idle, or some IDE? What happens if you put `'echo'` instead of `r'C:\Prog...\myApp.exe'`?

Comment: got error:
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 29, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: good. It means that your environment doesn't hide stderr. Do you run it from the command-line, idle, or some IDE?